# Access 2010: Can't access query after splitting DB

Tags: ms-access

I split my DB and now when I try to change some information on a few queries, I can't access them. I have a front end and a back end and understand that I should make changes to queries/forms via the front end, but they are grayed out and inaccessible.

At this point, I tried unsplitting the DB (which I believe I did), but I *still* can't edit those queries or forms.

I can click on the query/form and see the result of it, but I can't get to design view to edit it.

Comment: Can you edit them through your backend file? Also, did you successfully link the backend and front-end (it should be done automatically when you use the wizard, unless you changed something)

Comment: @Scotch, since the OP is asking about queries, it wouldn't make sense to do that on the back end since the queries are (or should be) stored in the front.

Comment: Hi Pam, welcome to SO.  Do you have any forms or reports open when you try to do this? These may have a property (I think Modal) that describe your problem well.  Try closing any other objects you have open first and see if you can open the query then.

Comment: @PowerUser Does it not make sense to ask if he can access his queries on the backend? My first instinct is that his database was not properly split and his tables aren't linked. OR he/she saved it as an aacdr or some other runtime application.

Comment: You might have a point there.  I was thinking about a proper split and that this is a standard accdb or accde.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a shot in the dark and saying that in the process of splitting your database, you either created your front-end in an accdr or accde format (a runtime application). The purpose of this is that you **shouldn't** be able to open queries or forms or tables in design view on the front end. You can just open your database and save it again as an accdb file and continue as normal.

If you're having other problems with the linked tables, I suggest you open the `Linked Table Manager` and refresh the links (if you moved the backend file, this is necessary).

I would recommend trying to proceed as normal by using `Shift Bypass` just to be sure. ( Hold the shift key when you start the database. Then attempt to modify in design view).

If these fail, I would attempt to copy the queries and /or forms if possible and create new ones.